# \thispagestyle and \pagestyle with packages fancyhdr and extramarks causes confusion

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing a scientific article using the article class. I have encountered some issues with my page headings that I have defined through the packages "fancyhdr" and "extramarks". I have 3 pagestyles: (1) "ttlpage" is used for the first page of the document only, (2) "simple" is used for the table of contents only and (3) "main" is used for the rest of the article document. See my code below.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\fancypagestyle{ttlpage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{First page head}
}

\fancypagestyle{simple}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\firstleftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\lastrightmark}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{ttlpage} % Causes problems.
%\pagestyle{ttlpage} % Works fine.
first page
\newpage

\pagestyle{empty} % With \thispagestyle above, causes missing \firstleftmark              and \lastrightmark
%\pagestyle{simple} % With \thispagestyle above, causes "CONTENTS" to be   printed instead of "INTRODUCTION",
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagestyle{main}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Foo}

\end{document}
```

If I use `\thispagestyle{ttlpage}` for the first page and then `\pagestyle{simple}` before `\tableofcontents` and `\pagestyle{main}` before the first section then `\firstleftmark` and `\lastrightmark` will print "Contents" in the headers of the following pages in the document, which is not what I want.
If I change `\pagestyle{simple}` to `\pagestyle{empty}` `\fristleftmark` and `\lastrightmark` will print nothing.

I managed to solve the problem by changing `\thispagestyle{ttlpage}` to `\pagestyle{ttlpage}`.
I don't see why this would solve the problem and I would really like to know why there is a difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are `\firstleftmark` and `lastrightmark` supposed to print here?

Comment: Move `\pagestyle{simple}` before `\begin{document}` (default style).

Comment: `\fristleftmark` is supposed to print the first section on the page - here Introduction. `\lastrightmark` prints the last subsection on the page - here Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in John Kormylo's comment you need to issue some `\pagestyle` command before `\begin{document}`.  Following the `fancyhdr` documentation this would be `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but any other of your defined styles would also do.

Below is an illustration with `\pagestyle{fancy}` showing a corrected header on the introduction page..

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\fancypagestyle{ttlpage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{First page head}
}

\fancypagestyle{simple}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\firstleftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\lastrightmark}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{ttlpage}

first page
\newpage

\pagestyle{simple} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagestyle{main}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Foo}

\end{document}
```